# Eclipse error parser ignores template "call stack"

Tags: c++, eclipse, templates, error-handling

g++ outputs template instantiation errors as something like:

> In file included from ...
>   *file*: In instantiation of ...
>   *file:line:pos* required from ...
>   *file2:line:pos* required from ...
>   *and so on*

But the error parser detects only the first "required from" line with the effect that you can't jump directly to the source code position. Is it possible to change that? I often find myself in need to check the complete callstack to find the mistake and that would be quite convenient...